# Checking Functionality of GIS layers of map services hosted by Geocortex and Flex applications

Tags: python, arcgis-10.3, flex, geocortex

I would like to be able to run a python script each morning that checks each sites map service layers for proper functionality.  Currently we have 10 sites with map services hosted by Geocortex and Flex.

I am able to run a script to open our sites in a browser and return a url code if they are up and running using

```
import webbrowser
url = 'http://entgisweb01/CountyView/'
webbrowser.open_new(url)

import urllib2

def main():
  # open a connection to a URL using urllib2
  webUrl = urllib2.urlopen("http://gis.ventura.org/CountyViewNew")

 # get the result code and print it
  print "result code: " + str(webUrl.getcode())
  print "http://gis.ventura.org/CountyViewNew"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

I would like to be able to check the layers of each map service within the sites using a python code instead of simply opening the site in a browser.

Comment: I think that you may need to look at the ArcGIS API for Python: https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2017/12/22/turbocharge-your-python-scripts-with-arcgis-api-for-python-v1-3/

Comment: Yes, the ArcGIS API can do that, but all you really need is a list of service URLs and a "?f=json" appended to return service status...  maybe 10 more lines of Python code.

Answer (score 1):

There must be tools to check if all your ArcGIS map services are still running.
You could simply do a http GET on each of the map service URls

1. GET (urlopen) http://gis.ventura.org/arcgis/rest/AssessorParcelMap/MapServer
2. Store the response. see if it is an error 
   Look for "Error: Service AssessorParcelMap/MapServer not found Code: 500"
3. If the ArcGIS map service is available, it will return the list of layers etc.

(This won't test if one of the layer is not accessible)